# Como usar Android.Hardware.Camera2 em Xamarin

Tags: xamarin-forms, xamarin.android, android-camera

Estou com algumas dificuldades em perceber como se usa

> Android.Hardware.Camera2;

em como funciona o método OpenCamera() e o que entra como parâmetro em AvailabilityCallback.

Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    CameraManager cameraManager = ((CameraManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService));
    //AvailabilityCallback stateCallback = ;

    Control.Preview = cameraManager.OpenCamera(cameraManager.GetCameraIdList()[0], WHAT_HERE?, null);
 }
 else
 {
    Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
 }
```

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uso da classe AvailabilityCallback

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic/Camera2Basic/Listeners/CameraStateListener.cs